# Composition of jets

Tags: taylor-expansion, function-and-relation-composition

I was reading that for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(0)=0$ and a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, $J(g\circ f)=J(g)\circ J(f)$ where $J(f)$ denotes the Taylor series of $f$.

I was searching, first by myself and then online a proof of that, but I could'nt find anyone.

Does someone have a source explaining it or any hint I could use?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far (by yourself I mean) ? Have you tried perhaps using the differential of a composite and the characterization of the (truncated) Taylor series with those differentials ?

Comment: I've consider the differential of a composite. The problem is here that I also need the higher differential of a composite, and I don't know any general formula for it.

Comment: I must admit, I've never thought about iterating the formula to the differentials themselves, I bet this must become ugly very soon... I was just suggesting an idea, I have no clue whether this would work or not, I'm sorry ! This is asking for the "functoriality of the jet", perhaps this would help with searching on the web ? (Although the nlab article is way beyond the scope of the question, and the rest seems like it's leading nowhere...)